# Google Map How to add Second location in map-active.js

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, google-maps

Hi Friends i cant able to find the solution for map-active.js file i think JS expert can do easily can u please help me i will share the   map-active.js file 
here only mention one location i want add one more location how it possible 
...?

```js
// google map
function initialize() {
  var grayStyles =[{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#e9e9e9"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f5f5f5"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":29},{"weight":0.2}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":18}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f5f5f5"},{"lightness":21}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#dedede"},{"lightness":21}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":16}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":36},{"color":"#333333"},{"lightness":40}]},{"elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"},{"lightness":19}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#fefefe"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#fefefe"},{"lightness":17},{"weight":1.2}]}] 
 var mapOptions = {
 zoom: 12,
 styles: grayStyles,
 hue: '#E9E5DC',
 scrollwheel: false,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(9.967027, 76.243499),
  
 };
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'),
 mapOptions);
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: map.getCenter(),
  animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
  icon: './assets/img/map.png',
  map: map
 });  
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you added the first location, same way create new markers attached to same map.

```
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: LOCATION_1_LAT, lng: LOCATION_1_LON},
        animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
        icon: './assets/img/map.png',
        map: map
    });

var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: LOCATION_2_LAT, lng: LOCATION_2_LON},
            animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
            icon: './assets/img/map.png',
            map: map
        });
```

**Demo here:** https://jsfiddle.net/sz9gkox6/

Comment: How we add to locations i mean this value lat and longitude [ center: new google.maps.LatLng(9.967027, 76.243499)] need to duplicated this also than only will works

Comment: If you want to use latitude and longitude for marker location, just replace `position: map.getCenter(),` with `position: {lat: LOCATION_1_LAT, lng: LOCATION_1_LON},` Replace `LOCATION_1_LAT` and `LOCATION_1_LON` with correct coordinates.

Comment: What are your coordinates where you want to put markers?